# Only circle shape from Inkscape Pixelate (Screenshot attached)

Tags: inkscape

Circle drawn in Inkscape is pixelate.

It does happen only with circle.
With square and text it doesn't.

I tried keep **Antialiasing** *on* and *off* but it doesn't worked.

I'm using **Inkscape 0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)**

On **Debian 10.6**

[image]

> I've zoomed it and taken screenshot to show, cause it looks same when zoomed in or out.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I can't see anything wrong with your screenshot.  All computer screens are made of pixels, and so ultimately even vector images need to be rendered with pixels to view them on a computer screen.  Yes, you may notice pixels more on the edge of a circle, or lines that are not horizontal or vertical, and not at all on a square. But that's totally normal.

Comment: Thank you Billy. I thought it's something wrong with circle. Thank you so much for time and efforts. Have a great time 